# In Kibana, how do I regex a field for a value with spaces?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Kibana v4.5.x

I want to search for the following logs in my index with a field called "msgbody."

```
Task lge005.5 boundary start: Remaining system memory before = 312641976
Task lge005.5 boundary end: Remaining system memory after = 310773144
Task lge007.5 boundary start: Remaining system memory before = 312641976
Task lge007.5 boundary end: Remaining system memory after = 310773144
```

I've tried the following to no avail, that is, search result is empty.

```
msgbody:/Task lge00[57].5 boundary/
msgbody.raw:Task lge00[57].5 boundary/
```

I can search for the following, but it returns more results than just the above logs.

```
msgbody:/lge00[57].5/
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Please add the full search query you are sending to your question. This way, it is easier to give you a relevant answer.

Comment: @ChristianHäckh, what do you mean by "full search query?" "msgbody:/Task lge00[57].5 boundary/" is the full search query that I put in the search field in Kibana. IOW, how can I search the msgbody field to produce ONLY the (sample) logs I put in my OP.

Comment: My bad, I was referencing to the resulting ES query. Does anything keep you from just searching for msgbody: "Task lge005.5 boundary" OR msgbody: "Task lge007.5 boundary"?

Comment: @ChristianHäckh, yes I need both to get a clear picture of the flow of events.